# Repeater field on a table [formidable forms]

Tags: html, wordpress, repeater, formidable

Hello there is my question:

i create a formular using formidable forms plugin on wordpress. My client ask me if it's possible to visualize the information on a table before submitting the forms.

Retrieving informations of different fields on a table using an html field is not to complicated but when its from a repeater field it gets tricky. I try to use the [foreach] functions but it seems not working the same as for a view.

Any help would be appreciated.

He is the code i use for retrieving the information of the repeater field:

```
Commande n°: <strong>[601]</strong> | Traitée par <strong>[606]</strong>
Demandeur: <strong>[609]</strong> | 
<table style="width: 1350px;">
<tbody>

<tr style="background-color: #006039;">
<th style="font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; padding-right:30px">N° article</th>
<th style="font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; padding-right:30px">Désignation</th>
<th style="font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; padding-right:30px">Quantité</th>

</tr>
[foreach 264]
<tr>
<td>[652]</td>
<td>[653]</td>
</tr>
[/foreach 264]
</tbody>
</table>
```